# How to bulid Tensorflow new GPU op

Tags: tensorflow

I followed the Tensorflow [Add a new op tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op), and it says

```
TF_CFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))') )
TF_LFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))') )
g++ -std=c++11 -shared zero_out.cc -o zero_out.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2
```

However, I met the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ./encoding_gpu.so: undefined symbol: _Z29ScaledL2ForwardKernelLauncherPKfS0_S0_iiiPf
```

I think it only considers the CPU ops, and I am wondering how to build GPU ops with the `.cu` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow actually provides instructions for compile GPU ops, check it at [gpu support](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#gpu_support).

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -c -o cuda_op_kernel.cu.o cuda_op_kernel.cu.cc \
  ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC

g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o cuda_op_kernel.so cuda_op_kernel.cc \
  cuda_op_kernel.cu.o ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} -fPIC -lcudart ${TF_LFLAGS[@]}
```